# How to use data validation based on 2D array or row and column of tickboxes in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, microsoft-excel, excel-online

Here, I'm attaching the part of the sheet which contains the tickboxes.
[image]

Objective is to format the column A with green or red background colour.
Rules:

- Data in column A should be green, if any of the tick boxes of it's row contains TRUE value.
- Data in column A should be red, if none of the tick boxes of it's row is TRUE.

Here, I tried by manually repeating the formula.

[image]

Note: I also tried using all other combinations of **$B$2 or $B2 or B$2** too.
Assumptions: It has maximum 17 columns and up to Kth column.

Comment: Are we talking about data validation or conditional formatting? In any case I think it is better that you give us the link to your sheet

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

The values of cells with a checkbox are either TRUE or FALSE.

To return TRUE if at least one checkbox is selected, use the [**OR() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en#null). And for the opposite effect, use the negation of the same value - the [**NOT() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en#null) will do this.

[image: Using OR and NOT]

The formulas for the conditions will be as follows:

```
=OR(B2:K2)
=NOT(OR(B2:K2))
```